# Drain connections on restart of NGINX process?

Tags: nginx, centos7

I'm using NGINX 1.8.1 on CentOS 6 and 7. During our deploys, it is required that NGINX is stopped, the deploy executes, and NGINX starts again. Unfortunately, NGINX during a stop seems to just 500 all connections. As I'm using Ansible to update 2/10 hosts at a time, it's likely therefore that many of our clients will get 500'd throughout our deploy process.

Is there a way via NGINX settings to have the NGINX process drain all live connections (ie wait for them to complete) while rejecting all new connections during a stop?

I know that Amazon's Elastic Load Balancers [do have this functionality](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-connection-draining-remove-instances-from-service-with-care/), is there an equivalent for NGINX?

Comment: The upgrade process is similar, it may have some clues that you can use, but isn't an answer as such https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-nginx-in-place-without-dropping-client-connections

Comment: "[...] it is required that NGINX is stopped, the deploy executes, and NGINX starts again. [...]" Why is that?

Comment: Bad downstream race condition that we cannot address.

Comment: Besides: What about let the firewall block NEW connections but allow RELATED, ESTABLISHED?

Comment: @gf_ that would make a lot of sense, can you provide an answer with some iptables magick?

Answer (score 4):

According to the comments, you could try to solve this using a firewall:

- Task: Block incoming new connections, but keep related and established ones
- Try: `iptables -I INPUT -j DROP -p tcp --syn --destination-port 80` (or 443, whatever applies to your setup) to set the rule, thus blocking new traffic
- Do your deployment...
- Try: `iptables -D INPUT -j DROP -p tcp --syn --destination-port 80` (or 443, whatever applies to your setup) to revert the rule, thus allowing new traffic
- Note: I've just tested this shortly, it worked as expected. But: Please don't take this for granted, and test for yourself as well. Feedback welcome...

**Edit:** As @Guntram Blohm pointed out in the comments, better to use `iptables -I` instead of `iptables -A`. Changed this appropriately in the above code.

Comment: Warning: if there are already some iptables entries, they might handle the packet before it ever gets to your appended, i.e. last, rule. Better use `-I` instead of `-A`.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Thanks for your comment, good point! I've changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Send nginx the "QUIT" signal to perform a [**graceful shutdown**](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/#stopping-or-restarting-nginx), which stops listening for new connections but allows workers to continue to serve active connections.

It's worth distinguishing between graceful shutdown and *connection draining*; graceful shutdown affects how NGINX deals with incoming connections while the server is shutting down, but connection draining (which as Martijn Heemels mentioned is a feature of NGINX Plus) deals with how NGINX removes a backend server from service when acting as a load balancer. From your question, it sounds like you're more interested in the former.

Comment: As an aside, on CentOS 7, SystemD defines `ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID`. It appears that on CentOS 6, the init script sends a `TERM` rather than `QUIT`, and this may be the source of our problems.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, connection draining is only available in the commercial version, Nginx Plus.

There's a description of the feature here: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-r5-released/

It's part of the [ngx_http_upstream_conf_module module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_conf_module.html#drain).